# How to draw table border in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I'm new to libgdx and I'm currently working on TableLayout and wondering how could I draw borders for each cells.

I've done some research on this but it seems that I could come up with this solution only:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828423/drawing-table-borders-in-libgdx-0-9-7

However, turning on the debug option would be a bit dumb and it's not what I want. I'd like to control the color, thickness of the cell border. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: There's also someone suggesting to use a ninepatch as background for the table. You could try to get the tables size and but a ninepatch behind/in front of it with a transparent middlepart and visible outer part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in function for this.

You have a few options though:

1. Use a 9-patch for table background with a border (thats what I do)
2. Place another table underneath the main table, and make the size a bit bigger so you can see the edges, giving the impression of a border. This is probably your best choice since you want to control color/thickness etc.

Comment: Still no better solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides the ones mentioned is to use Pixmap to draw the rectangle border and then use it as the background. It will give the idea of a border. The code below uses KTX so LibGDX with Kotlin.

```
    val pixmap = Pixmap(64, 64, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)        
    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK)
    pixmap.drawRectangle(0,0,64,64)
    val borderTexture = TextureRegionDrawable(Texture(pixmap))
    pixmap.dispose()
    
// initialize table etc...
table.background = borderTexture
```